# operate file in background?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am writing an elisp function for having a short help description for a symbol:

```
(defun set-up-tooltip()
    ;; search for the text to be highlighted
    ...
    (add-text-properties (match-beginning 0)
                         (match-end 0)
                         '(mouse-face highlight
                                      help-echo (get-help-text (match-beginning 0)))
```

the `(get-help-text )` function needs to open another file to search for the text. The question is: How do I open this file in the background so that user does not notice? I tried:

```
(defun get-help-text(
    (save-excursion
      (with-temp-buffer
         (find-file "lookup-file")
         ;;search for the text
         ...
             )))))
```

Here the file which is opened in the temp buffer opens in the window where I call the function and not in the background. Is there a idiomatic way for such tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the function `insert-file-contents`:

```
insert-file-contents is a built-in function in `C source code'.

(insert-file-contents FILENAME &optional VISIT BEG END REPLACE)

Insert contents of file FILENAME after point.
```

Use that instead of `find-file` inside your `with-temp-buffer`, and you should achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the function `find-file-noselect`.